# Send email report after test execution in Azure pipelin

Tags: c#, azure, selenium, c#-4.0

I have implemented C# selenium automation script with Azure pipeline. I wanted to send the execution test result to my email id. Is there any way we can achieve this?

Comment: Which do you have an issue with, obtaining Selenium results or using c# to send an email?

Answer (score 1):

For now , you can only write a custom extension to send an email with the test result which you can call it from your Azure devops pipeline.

But you can use below set of API for getting the test result.

```
GET https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/test/Runs/{runId}/results?api-version=5.0
```

with optional parameter.

```
GET https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/test/Runs/{runId}/results?detailsToInclude={detailsToInclude}&$skip={$skip}&$top={$top}&outcomes={outcomes}&api-version=5.0
```

where params are :

[image]

here is the sample response:

```
{
  "count": 3,
  "value": [
    {
      "id": 100000,
      "project": {
        "id": "5c3d39df-a0cb-49da-be01-42e53792c0e1",
        "name": "Fabrikam-Fiber-TFVC",
        "url": "https://dev.azure.com/fabrikam/_apis/projects/Fabrikam-Fiber-TFVC"
      },
      "startedDate": "2016-07-13T11:12:48.487Z",
      "completedDate": "2016-07-13T11:12:48.493Z",
      "durationInMs": 4,
      "outcome": "Passed",
      "revision": 1,
      "runBy": {
        "id": "a5cbf24d-799f-452e-82be-f049a85b5895",
        "displayName": "Fabrikam",
        "uniqueName": "fabrikamfiber.vsin@hotmail.com",
        "url": "https://dev.azure.com/fabrikam/_apis/Identities/a5cbf24d-799f-452e-82be-f049a85b5895",
        "imageUrl": "https://dev.azure.com/fabrikam/_api/_common/identityImage?id=a5cbf24d-799f-452e-82be-f049a85b5895"
      },
      "state": "Completed",
      "testCase": {
        "name": "Pass1"
      },
      "testRun": {
        "id": "16",
        "name": "VSTest Test Run release any cpu",
        "url": "https://dev.azure.com/fabrikam/Fabrikam-Fiber-TFVC/_apis/test/Runs/16"
      },
      "lastUpdatedDate": "2016-07-13T11:12:49.123Z",
      "lastUpdatedBy": {
        "id": "375baa5b-5148-4e89-a549-ec202b722d89",
        "displayName": "Project Collection Build Service (fabrikam)",
        "uniqueName": "Build\\78b5727d-4a24-4ec8-9caf-704685572174",
        "url": "https://vssps.dev.azure.com/fabrikam/_apis/Identities/375baa5b-5148-4e89-a549-ec202b722d89",
        "imageUrl": "https://dev.azure.com/fabrikam/_api/_common/identityImage?id=375baa5b-5148-4e89-a549-ec202b722d89"
      },
      "priority": 0,
      "computerName": "TASKAGENT5-0055",
      "build": {
        "id": "5",
        "name": "20160713.2",
        "url": "https://dev.azure.com/fabrikam/_apis/build/Builds/5"
      },
      "createdDate": "2016-07-13T11:12:49.123Z",
      "url": "https://dev.azure.com/fabrikam/Fabrikam-Fiber-TFVC/_apis/test/Runs/16/Results/100000",
      "failureType": "None",
      "automatedTestStorage": "unittestproject1.dll",
      "automatedTestType": "UnitTest",
      "automatedTestTypeId": "13cdc9d9-ddb5-4fa4-a97d-d965ccfc6d4b",
      "automatedTestId": "aefba017-ab06-be36-6b92-de4e29836f72",
      "area": {
        "id": "37528",
        "name": "Fabrikam-Fiber-TFVC",
        "url": "vstfs:///Classification/Node/ebe8ac79-8d9f-4a5b-8d0a-c3095c81e70e"
      },
      "testCaseTitle": "Pass1",
      "customFields": [],
      "automatedTestName": "UnitTestProject1.UnitTest1.Pass1"
    },
    {
      "id": 100001,
      "project": {
        "id": "5c3d39df-a0cb-49da-be01-42e53792c0e1",
        "name": "Fabrikam-Fiber-TFVC",
        "url": "https://dev.azure.com/fabrikam/_apis/projects/Fabrikam-Fiber-TFVC"
      },
      "startedDate": "2016-07-13T11:12:48.547Z",
      "completedDate": "2016-07-13T11:12:48.62Z",
      "durationInMs": 74,
      "outcome": "Failed",
      "revision": 1,
      "runBy": {
        "id": "a5cbf24d-799f-452e-82be-f049a85b5895",
        "displayName": "Fabrikam-Fiber-TFVC",
        "uniqueName": "fabrikamfiber.vsin@hotmail.com",
        "url": "https://vssps.dev.azure.com/fabrikam/_apis/Identities/a5cbf24d-799f-452e-82be-f049a85b5895",
        "imageUrl": "https://dev.azure.com/fabrikam/_api/_common/identityImage?id=a5cbf24d-799f-452e-82be-f049a85b5895"
      },
      "state": "Completed",
      "testCase": {
        "name": "Fail1"
      },
      "testRun": {
        "id": "16",
        "name": "VSTest Test Run release any cpu",
        "url": "https://dev.azure.com/fabrikam/Fabrikam-Fiber-TFVC/_apis/test/Runs/16"
      },
      "lastUpdatedDate": "2016-07-13T11:12:49.123Z",
      "lastUpdatedBy": {
        "id": "375baa5b-5148-4e89-a549-ec202b722d89",
        "displayName": "Project Collection Build Service (fabrikam)",
        "uniqueName": "Build\\78b5727d-4a24-4ec8-9caf-704685572174",
        "url": "https://vssps.dev.azure.com/fabrikam/_apis/Identities/375baa5b-5148-4e89-a549-ec202b722d89",
        "imageUrl": "https://dev.azure.com/fabrikam/_api/_common/identityImage?id=375baa5b-5148-4e89-a549-ec202b722d89"
      },
      "priority": 10,
      "computerName": "TASKAGENT5-0055",
      "build": {
        "id": "5",
        "name": "20160713.2",
        "url": "https://dev.azure.com/fabrikam/_apis/build/Builds/5"
      },
      "errorMessage": "Assert.Fail failed. ",
      "createdDate": "2016-07-13T11:12:49.123Z",
      "url": "https://dev.azure.com/fabrikam/Fabrikam-Fiber-TFVC/_apis/test/Runs/16/Results/100001",
      "failureType": "None",
      "automatedTestStorage": "unittestproject1.dll",
      "automatedTestType": "UnitTest",
      "automatedTestTypeId": "13cdc9d9-ddb5-4fa4-a97d-d965ccfc6d4b",
      "automatedTestId": "7c66fbda-2d0e-a714-e18d-83c0464019a5",
      "area": {
        "id": "37528",
        "name": "Fabrikam-Fiber-TFVC",
        "url": "vstfs:///Classification/Node/ebe8ac79-8d9f-4a5b-8d0a-c3095c81e70e"
      },
      "testCaseTitle": "Fail1",
      "stackTrace": "   at UnitTestProject1.UnitTest1.Fail1() in C:\\a\\1\\s\\UnitTestProject1\\UnitTestProject1\\UnitTest1.cs:line 20\r\n",
      "customFields": [],
      "failingSince": {
        "date": "2016-07-13T11:11:17.587Z",
        "build": {
          "id": 4,
          "definitionId": 0,
          "number": "20160713.1",
          "buildSystem": "Azure DevOps Services"
        }
      },
      "automatedTestName": "UnitTestProject1.UnitTest1.Fail1"
    },
    {
      "id": 100002,
      "project": {
        "id": "5c3d39df-a0cb-49da-be01-42e53792c0e1",
        "name": "Fabrikam-Fiber-TFVC",
        "url": "https://dev.azure.com/fabrikam/_apis/projects/Fabrikam-Fiber-TFVC"
      },
      "startedDate": "2016-07-13T11:12:48.623Z",
      "completedDate": "2016-07-13T11:12:48.623Z",
      "outcome": "NotExecuted",
      "revision": 1,
      "runBy": {
        "id": "a5cbf24d-799f-452e-82be-f049a85b5895",
        "displayName": "Fabrikam-Fiber-TFVC",
        "uniqueName": "fabrikamfiber.vsin@hotmail.com",
        "url": "https://vssps.dev.azure.com/fabrikam/_apis/Identities/a5cbf24d-799f-452e-82be-f049a85b5895",
        "imageUrl": "https://dev.azure.com/fabrikam/_api/_common/identityImage?id=a5cbf24d-799f-452e-82be-f049a85b5895"
      },
      "state": "Completed",
      "testCase": {
        "name": "Ignore1"
      },
      "testRun": {
        "id": "16",
        "name": "VSTest Test Run release any cpu",
        "url": "https://dev.azure.com/fabrikam/Fabrikam-Fiber-TFVC/_apis/test/Runs/16"
      },
      "lastUpdatedDate": "2016-07-13T11:12:49.123Z",
      "lastUpdatedBy": {
        "id": "375baa5b-5148-4e89-a549-ec202b722d89",
        "displayName": "Project Collection Build Service (fabrikam)",
        "uniqueName": "Build\\78b5727d-4a24-4ec8-9caf-704685572174",
        "url": "https://vssps.dev.azure.com/fabrikam/_apis/Identities/375baa5b-5148-4e89-a549-ec202b722d89",
        "imageUrl": "https://dev.azure.com/fabrikam/_api/_common/identityImage?id=375baa5b-5148-4e89-a549-ec202b722d89"
      },
      "priority": 20,
      "computerName": "TASKAGENT5-0055",
      "build": {
        "id": "5",
        "name": "20160713.2",
        "url": "https://dev.azure.com/fabrikam/_apis/build/Builds/5"
      },
      "createdDate": "2016-07-13T11:12:49.123Z",
      "url": "https://dev.azure.com/fabrikam/Fabrikam-Fiber-TFVC/_apis/test/Runs/16/Results/100002",
      "failureType": "None",
      "automatedTestStorage": "unittestproject1.dll",
      "automatedTestType": "UnitTest",
      "automatedTestTypeId": "13cdc9d9-ddb5-4fa4-a97d-d965ccfc6d4b",
      "automatedTestId": "ef9123e0-a097-7e9b-9a02-f526c7a640c0",
      "area": {
        "id": "37528",
        "name": "Fabrikam-Fiber-TFVC",
        "url": "vstfs:///Classification/Node/ebe8ac79-8d9f-4a5b-8d0a-c3095c81e70e"
      },
      "testCaseTitle": "Ignore1",
      "customFields": [],
      "automatedTestName": "UnitTestProject1.UnitTest1.Ignore1"
    }
  ]
}
```

You can write a custom utility in which you can write a function to get the test result and publish it using email and then later on you can call it from Azure devops pipeline task.

[Here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/extend/develop/add-build-task?view=azure-devops) you can find the sample doc for custom defined task.

Hope it helps.

Comment: I have added Generate Specflow Report and Send Email extension in my azure pipeline. But i am not sure how to implement. Have any one done? Ideally i am need to send the automation test result to my email id. I have been struggling for a month. I appreciated your help!